# LibGDX ButtonGroup Control How Many Buttons Can Be Down

Tags: java, android, button, libgdx

I'm a bit new to LibGDX and was wondering how I could control how many buttons can be in its down state at a time. The think I want to accomplish with these buttons is this: As soon as my finger touches one, it gets pressed, and only one can be pressed at a time, and if one of my fingers is on a button pressing it, and another finger presses another button, the initial one being pressed goes back to its up state, and the only way for that one to be pressed again is if I let go of my finger and press it again.

Anyway, here's my code. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
public MenuStateTest(GameStateManager gsm) {
    super(gsm);
    cam.setToOrtho(false, MyGame.WIDTH, MyGame.HEIGHT);

    fitViewport = new FitViewport(MyGame.WIDTH, MyGame.HEIGHT);

    stage = new Stage(fitViewport);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    font = new BitmapFont();
    skin = new Skin();

    buttonAtlas = new TextureAtlas("buttonTest.pack");
    skin.addRegions(buttonAtlas);
    textButtonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
    textButtonStyle.font = font;
    textButtonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("1BBlock");
    textButtonStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("T1BBlock");
    button = new TextButton("", textButtonStyle);
    stage.addActor(button);
    button.setPosition(20, 200);
    button.getStyle().checked = button.getStyle().down;

    button2Atlas = new TextureAtlas("Button2Test.pack");
    skin.addRegions(button2Atlas);
    textButtonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
    textButtonStyle.font = font;
    textButtonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("2BBlock");
    textButtonStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("T2BBlock");
    button2 = new TextButton("", textButtonStyle);
    stage.addActor(button2);
    button2.setPosition(175, 200);
    button2.getStyle().checked = button2.getStyle().down;

    button3Atlas = new TextureAtlas("Button3Test.pack");
    skin.addRegions(button3Atlas);
    textButtonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
    textButtonStyle.font = font;
    textButtonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("3BBlock");
    textButtonStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("T3BBlock");
    button3 = new TextButton("", textButtonStyle);
    stage.addActor(button3);
    button3.setPosition(330, 200);
    button3.getStyle().checked = button3.getStyle().down;

    ButtonGroup buttons = new ButtonGroup(button1, button2, button3);
    buttons.setMaxCheckCount(1);
}

@Override
protected void handleInput() {

}

@Override
protected void update(float dt) {
    stage.getViewport().update(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public MenuStateTest(GameStateManager gsm) {
    super(gsm);
    cam.setToOrtho(false, MyGame.WIDTH, MyGame.HEIGHT);

    fitViewport = new FitViewport(MyGame.WIDTH, MyGame.HEIGHT);

    stage = new Stage(fitViewport);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    font = new BitmapFont();
    skin = new Skin();

    buttonAtlas = new TextureAtlas("buttonTest.pack");
    skin.addRegions(buttonAtlas);
    textButtonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
    textButtonStyle.font = font;
    textButtonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("1BBlock");
    textButtonStyle.checked = skin.getDrawable("T1BBlock");
    button = new TextButton("", textButtonStyle);
    stage.addActor(button);
    button.setPosition(20, 200);

    button2Atlas = new TextureAtlas("Button2Test.pack");
    skin.addRegions(button2Atlas);
    textButtonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
    textButtonStyle.font = font;
    textButtonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("2BBlock");
    textButtonStyle.checked = skin.getDrawable("T2BBlock");
    button2 = new TextButton("", textButtonStyle);
    stage.addActor(button2);
    button2.setPosition(175, 200);

    button3Atlas = new TextureAtlas("Button3Test.pack");
    skin.addRegions(button3Atlas);
    textButtonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
    textButtonStyle.font = font;
    textButtonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("3BBlock");
    textButtonStyle.checked = skin.getDrawable("T3BBlock");
    button3 = new TextButton("", textButtonStyle);
    stage.addActor(button3);
    button3.setPosition(330, 200);

    ButtonGroup buttons = new ButtonGroup(button1, button2, button3);
    buttons.setMaxCheckCount(1);
}

@Override
protected void handleInput() {

}

@Override
protected void update(float dt) {
    stage.getViewport().update(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
}
```

Comment: Yes but the problem here is that the buttons only activate once I let go of my finger, I'm trying to figure out how to make it so that they activate as soon as I touch the button.

Comment: I would not presume to tell you what to do, though I'd suggest coming up with a simpler way how to setup your game controls. This is just personal opinion of course, but I can tell you if I was playing a game with controls like this, it would irritate the hell out of me :-). As a final note, if you insist on doing it this way, you can manually override handle input events and have a bunch of if-then-elses and maybe somebody will even suggest it - but it won't be me, especially if you'd like to learn how the library works to be able to use it well, it's just not the right thing to do. Good luck